# Callbacks before_save no me funciona ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

hola el error es que no me esta guardando el id como string en la variable
   fullnumid  solo quiero que se guarde cuando se crean,  gracias

```
after_create :guardar
 def guardar
  self.fullnumid = self.id.to_s
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Necsitas guardar el objeto después de asignar el valor a `fullnumid`; puedes hacerlo con `save!` o con `update!`:

Con `save!`:

```
def guardar
  self.fullnumid = id.to_s
  save!
end
```

Con `update!`:

```
def guardar
  update!(fullnumid: id.to_s)
end
```

Podrás notar el uso de `save!` y `update!` (con `!`), lo cual sirve para que, en caso que falle, se arroje un error (si quitas el `!` también funciona, pero no podrás ver el error en caso que el registro no se actualice).